# reading an image not successful with screenshots

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to add existing picture to Bitmap variable. My problem is in the screenshot below. I tried some examples but i couldn't read the picture.

[image]

Comment: The path is wrong. Take the `~` out.

Comment: Adding to what @asawyer said, WinForms doesn't understand the `~` character as you may be expecting if you're used to ASP .NET

Comment: asawyer, that should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Yes. The tilde sintax could be used in a web application for resolve virtual paths.

Comment: i took the ~ out but it still didn't see it @asawyer.

Comment: Is it still throwing the argument exception? I don't remember if `Bitmap` loads from relative paths. Try `new Bitmap(Application.StartupPath + "/../images/search.jpg");`

Comment: sorry I'm a asp.net developer and i didn't know about ~ character. But I still couldn't find the real path. I didn't want to use the path like C://etc..

Comment: when i type Bitmap search = new Bitmap("Images/Search.jpg") it throws ArgumentException which is Parameter is not valid.

Comment: it didn't work @asawyer

Comment: I dont know what to tell you then "it didn't work" isnt exactly usefull debugging information.

Comment: You need either a fully qualified path or a path relative to the current folder.

Comment: I could not figure out how to set a path to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I support the previous answers, that the problem is with the path. I suggest you verify it - by checking `File.Exists(path)` and `MessageBox.Show` of the result.

Also, check for the properties of the `Search.jpg` file. Does it have `Copy to output folder`?

Comment: Thanks @kobigurk that's the correct answer! it had do not copy in properties. Appreciated for your answer..

Comment: No problem, glad to assist

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears you want to use a relative path I will presume the path is relative to the application folder. Here is an example that gets the application's path and appends your Images path and file name to it.

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    AttackPerMinutesComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    var targets = AutoClickManager.GetAllTargets();
    TargetListGridView.DataSource = targets;
    Bitmap search = new Bitmap(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Images\\Search.jpg");
    ...
}
```

Comment: it still throws Argument Exception , Parameter is not valid.

Comment: @AnılCanlı That exception is thrown when the file is not found. Put a break point on the new Bitmap line and use the immediate window to check the complete path and file name. Is the file in that path?